# Multiplication of Matrix by vector in python is different when comparing with Matlab

Tags: python, matlab

I have a matrix `h` of size, for example, `4 x 4`, and a vector `y` of size `4 x 1`, I need to multiply the inverse of each column in H by the vector `y` and put the output in a vector.

I first did that operation using Matlab as below:

```
clear all 
clc 

h = [0.0937 + 1.5453i,  -0.1910 - 0.3741i,   1.4420 + 0.6273i,   0.0518 - 0.4653i; ...
    0.8537 + 0.9905i,  -0.2910 + 0.0131i,   0.2993 - 0.5929i,   0.6426 + 0.4098i;...
    0.3722 - 0.3470i,   0.0449 - 0.2985i,  -0.7595 - 0.1346i,  -1.2782 + 0.1877i; ...
    -0.8256 + 0.5255i,  -0.5318 - 0.0624i,  -0.5467 - 0.4118i,   0.0772 + 0.9888i]; 
y = [0.1037 + 0.1302i; 0.3676 - 0.0198i; 0.2380 + 0.2824i; 0.0557 - 0.4222i];

x2 = [];
for ii = 1 : size(h, 2)
             nn = h(:,ii); 
             x1 = pinv(nn)*y; 
             x2 = [x2 x1];
 end
```

The output result `x2` is a vector `4 x 1` as below:

```
x2 =

   0.0428 - 0.0041i  -0.3953 + 0.5110i   0.0698 + 0.1021i  -0.1423 - 0.1743i
```

I need to do the same process by python, .. I have already done it, but the results are not similar with that of MATLAB, .. the code is as below:

```
import numpy as np
h = np.array([[0.0937 + 1.5453j,  -0.1910 - 0.3741j,   1.4420 + 0.6273j,   0.0518 - 0.4653j],
   [0.8537 + 0.9905j,  -0.2910 + 0.0131j,  0.2993 - 0.5929j,   0.6426 + 0.4098j],
  [0.3722 - 0.3470j,   0.0449 - 0.2985j,  -0.7595 - 0.1346j,  -1.2782 + 0.1877j],
  [-0.8256 + 0.5255j,  -0.5318 - 0.0624j,  -0.5467 - 0.4118j,   0.0772 + 0.9888j]])
y = np.array([[0.1037 + 0.1302j], [0.3676 - 0.0198j], [0.2380 + 0.2824j], [0.0557 - 0.4222j]])
n = 3
x2 = np.zeros((1, 4), dtype=np.complex)
for ii in range(n):
    x2[: , ii] = np.linalg.pinv(h[: , ii].reshape(-1,1)).dot(y)

print(x2)
```

the output resluts of code done in python is as below :

```
x3 = [[ 0.04280434-0.00414509j -0.39528813+0.51101969j  0.06979707+0.10208365j 0.        +0.j        ]]
```

Is there something wrong in the code of python? or that is normal results ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is normal (mostly). There is one small error, namely that the python `range` function is exclusive (does not go up to `n`). You will notice that the latter (python numpy) is just a more accurate version of the former (MATLAB). (At least the first three terms suggest so, the fourth term does deviate for the aforementioned reasons). As for why it is not a 1d vector, it is no surprise as numpy preserves the number of dimensions.